# Javascript Read Array Values from Function dynamically

Tags: javascript

How can I pass a array name into a function and read values dynamically?

***Dynamically i have generated array as follows***

```
fruits[0] = "Banana";
fruits[1] = "Orange";
fruits[2] = "Apple";
```

//Hyperlink to activate function below

```
I have a function in hyeperlink <a href="javascript: activate('1', 'fruits')">Click Me</a>
```

Below is the function

```
function activate(idNumber, arrayName)
{
  alert('id is:'+ idNumber); **//Working** 
  alert(arrayName[idNumber]); **//Not working must print fruits[1]**

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the scope in which 'fruits' is defined.

Assuming it is global, `window[arrayName]` will get it when `arrayName=='fruits'`. This is because `window` holds a reference to all global objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bro! you saved my day! This one exactly fixed my problem! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in the letters "f","r","u","i","t", and "s" instead of the variable, just remove the quotes from around the variable:

```
<a href="javascript: activate('1', fruits)">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: HI Kranklin, Yes i did try passing fruits directly but it says undefined now

Comment: Where are you defining `fruits`? Is your code exactly like what you have or do you have a line like `fruits = []` that is before the assignments? If not then just try `fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple"]`. Otherwise a http://jsfiddle.net would be nice to help figure out what's wrong.